# Why is it correct to use "of" in one case but wrong in the other?

Tags: prepositions

> What color coat will she buy?
>
> What form of pancakes will she make?

Is there a general rule? A rule of thumb, maybe?

Comment: This has been discussed lot on 'English Language & Usage', for example https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/how-big-of-a-problem-vs-how-big-a-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @KateBunting can't see how it answers my question.

Comment: Well, how about https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162122/what-colour-eyes?noredirect=1&lq=1